# Windows is not loading

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, reboot

I have partitioned my drive to have the option to boot from Windows 7 or 8.

Recently when I power up my laptop it goes through an endless power on, initial boot sequence, black screen with a cursor and repeats the sequence.

**Initial Trouble Shooting**

- I'm able to get into the BIOS
- I've removed and reinserted the battery
- I've attempted different sequences with the memory sticks and slots (12, 1X, X2, 2X, X1, 21)
- I've booted off a USB drive with Ubuntu on it and I'm able to see my main hard drive and files.

I'm assuming I'll need to reinstall Windows but I wanted to verify this first.

Based on this is there any other troubleshooting I should be doing?

Comment: if you hold CTRL during boot, does anything change?

Comment: It would appear to be the OS is unhappy!

Comment: Do repair action through your OS Disk...

Comment: @FrankThomas no it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is what I did. I need WIN 7 to remote into my office so I:

- Booted Ubuntu from a USB, and manually backed up my data to an
  external HD
- Installed WIN 7 and in the process merged the two partitions back together.
- WIN 8 complained and WIN 7 was not a clean install
- Booted Ubuntu again, formatted the merged partition
- Installed WIN 7

In the end, I don't know if the issue was with WIN 7 or WIN